# How to use PGF mathematical expressions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an array with values. I wish to do some calculation on it and find than the maximum.

See the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  %value array with 80 values
  \def\Rtable{{100, 100.391, 100.781, 101.172, 101.562, 101.953, 102.343, 102.733, 103.123, 103.513, 103.903, 104.292, 104.682, 105.071, 105.46, 105.849, 106.238, 106.627, 107.016, 107.405, 107.794, 108.182, 108.57, 108.959, 109.347, 109.735, 110.123, 110.51, 110.898, 111.286, 111.673, 112.06, 112.447, 112.835, 113.221, 113.608, 113.995, 114.382, 114.768, 115.155, 115.541, 115.927, 116.313, 116.699, 117.085, 117.47, 117.856, 118.241, 118.627, 119.012, 119.397, 119.782, 120.167, 120.552, 120.936, 121.321, 121.705, 122.09, 122.474, 122.858, 123.242, 123.626, 124.009, 124.393, 124.777, 125.16, 125.543, 125.926, 126.309, 126.692, 127.075, 127.458, 127.84, 128.223, 128.605, 128.987, 129.37, 129.752, 130.133, 130.515, 130.897}}
  %initializes the result value
  \def\RiValue{0}
  Test the result value: \RiValue.\\[\baselineskip]
  %calculation
  \foreach \i in {0, ..., 80}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{abs(\Rtable[\i] - 100 - 3.0897 / 8 * \i)}%this line works (see link below)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RiValue}{max(\RiValue, \pgfmathresult)}
    %the max routine seems not doing the right thing, because \RiValue stores every value of the abs routine
    %also \RiValue and \pgfmathresult have both the same value in each iteration
    \i: \RiValue\ and \pgfmathresult\newline
  }\\[\baselineskip]
  %\RiValue seems not changed at all
  The result value at the end: \RiValue.
\end{document}
```

The [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/is-it-possible-to-use-arrays-in-a-function-of-tikz-datavisualization) to my other question (where I wish use this calculation).

What do I wrong?

Comment: Do you do anything wrong? What makes you think so?

Comment: Hello @cfr! Thank you for your comment and answer! Sorry for my bad explanation. You are right in this case the `abs` routine does nothing (I have other cases in my task, there I need the `abs`). I didn't knew that in TeX a loop don't change a global variable without special commands (`\global\let`). So thank you for this information! You have intuitive solved my question despite my bad explanation. Your answer is exactly what I wanted! Thank you and shame on me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want to happen. `\RiValue` is only redefined locally, though, so it is zero at the start of each loop. Since none of the values produced are negative, the calculated value is always the maximum.

Do you expect something like this?

[image: possible desiderata]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  %value array with 80 values
  \def\Rtable{{100, 100.391, 100.781, 101.172, 101.562, 101.953, 102.343, 102.733, 103.123, 103.513, 103.903, 104.292, 104.682, 105.071, 105.46, 105.849, 106.238, 106.627, 107.016, 107.405, 107.794, 108.182, 108.57, 108.959, 109.347, 109.735, 110.123, 110.51, 110.898, 111.286, 111.673, 112.06, 112.447, 112.835, 113.221, 113.608, 113.995, 114.382, 114.768, 115.155, 115.541, 115.927, 116.313, 116.699, 117.085, 117.47, 117.856, 118.241, 118.627, 119.012, 119.397, 119.782, 120.167, 120.552, 120.936, 121.321, 121.705, 122.09, 122.474, 122.858, 123.242, 123.626, 124.009, 124.393, 124.777, 125.16, 125.543, 125.926, 126.309, 126.692, 127.075, 127.458, 127.84, 128.223, 128.605, 128.987, 129.37, 129.752, 130.133, 130.515, 130.897}}
  %initializes the result value
  \def\RiValue{0}
  Test the result value: \RiValue.\par
  %calculation
  \foreach \i in {0, ..., 80}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{abs(\Rtable[\i] - 100 - 3.0897 / 8 * \i)}%this line works (see link below)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RiValue}{max(\RiValue, \myresult)}
    %the max routine seems not doing the right thing, because \RiValue stores every value of the abs routine
    %also \RiValue and \pgfmathresult have both the same value in each iteration
    \i: \RiValue\ and \myresult\par
    \global\let\RiValue\RiValue
  }
  %\RiValue seems not changed at all
  The result value at the end: \RiValue.
\end{document}
```